# showing a string that does not exists in array , with wrong index

Tags: c++

can somebody explain this me
i wrote binary search in c++ , for array of strings

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#define ARR_LENGTH(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]))

int binary_search(string names[], int len, const string target)
{
  int low = 0;
  int high = len - 1;
  int mid = 0;
  string item;
  while (low <= high) {
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    item = names[mid];
    if (item == target) {
      return mid;
    }
    if (strcmp(target.c_str(), item.c_str()) < 0) {
      high = mid - 1;
    } else
      low = mid + 1;
  }
  return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  string names[] = {
    "ali",
    "arsham",
    "bahman",
    "bahram",
    "bizhan",
    "darioush",
    "erfan",
    "parsa",
    "setayesh"
  };
  int index = binary_search(names, ARR_LENGTH(names), "ali2");
  cout << "given index is : " << index << endl;
  cout << "founded name is : " << names[index] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

here is the program

problem is program is showing ali2, in second cout statement
but it does not exists in array, also index is -1
i tried that many time, but same result, showing not existing string

Comment: if the name does not exist then you are displaying `names[-1]` which has undefined behavior.  You need to print only if `index >= 0`

Comment: Cannot reproduce described (undefined) behavior. The program segfaults: https://godbolt.org/z/vYYxajs19

Comment: When index is `-1` you are out of bounds  in your access here: `names[index]`

Comment: also names[index] == "ali2" equals to true

Comment: ***also names[index] == "ali2" equals to true*** It could. Once you have undefined behavior anything can happen. You must prevent undefined behavior by skipping the: `cout << "founded name is : " << names[index] << endl;` line when index is less than 0.

Comment: ***so why it's not throwing an error ?*** The language is not required to throw an error for the case of undefined behavior.

Comment: Here is some info on UB: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: ah yes, but why it's not throwing an error ? it may cause some bugs i think, logical bug or ...

Comment: You will have to research undefined behavior for the info you seek. There should be many questions about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary search functions works as expected since it returns -1 (doesn't find 'ali2'). The question is why printing names[index] prints ali2. Furthermore, why can you even read a value from the names array when index is -1?

Remember that a C/C++ array is just a memory address. One of the dangers of C/C++ is that you are able to read memory that doesn't belong to you and in this case, you are reading values before the array. When you do this, it is undefined behavior and can lead to problems. In this case, one of the variables (ali2) happens to be stored right before the start of your array. You can also try reading names[-2] or names[-3], which would just be other variables or other data in your system. At some point, you may encounter a segmentation fault.

**How do you fix this?**

Once you get a return value from your function, you should check whether it is -1 and then handle the case appropriately.